# How to setup multiple WiFi networks?

Tags: networking, wifi, static-ip

I go back and forth from home to school with my Pi.  I just got the WiFi working last night at home using `wpa.conf` instead of `wpa_supplicant.conf` as the book I was using had the walk thru for that instead.  I've noticed lots seem to use `wpa_supplicant` but I not sure why...

Anyway, I know how to make the WiFi IP static for my home network but how do I set things up for auto-connecting to my school WiFi and use a different static IP for that network?

For the network do I just add another `network={}` in my `wpa.conf` file?
For the second static IP how do I bind that to the school network?

Comment: This question is quite old, and the answers are too -- about 5 years, and the most recent edits are three years old. What's the current technique for solving this problem?

Comment: @MikeB: A technique for [actively switching between Access Points is covered here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136933/83790) (posted Apr 6, 2022). The answer to this question is a simplification of the *"active switching"* answer because by default `wpa_supplicant` will choose the network with the strongest signal; i.e. the selection will be done *automatically* as long as the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file contains the specs for the networks.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

> This post was OK at the time for Wheezy. **DO NOT USE**

Edit **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** and add **id_str="school"** under the schools wpa info and **id_str="home"** under your homes wpa info.  Your file should now look similar to this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="SCHOOLS NETWORK NAME"
    psk="SCHOOLS PASSWORD"
    id_str="school"
}

network={
    ssid="HOME NETWORK NAME"
    psk="HOME PASSWORD"
    id_str="home"
}
```

Then set up **/etc/network/interfaces** with **iface school inet static** and **iface home inet static** in it so it looks like the following:

> This applies to Raspbian Wheezy prior to 2015-05-05 for later (and Jessie) See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface school inet static
address <school address>
gateway <school gateway>
netmask <school netmask>

iface home inet static
address <home address>
gateway <home gateway>
netmask <home netmask>
```

Comment: It might be worth noting: If I understand the documentation correctly, in order to use this approach, you must have and id_str property for EVERY network in your wpa_supplicant.conf file. Otherwise this won't work. Can you confirm?

Comment: I don't believe this to be the case.

Comment: This approach works, however, is it possible to switch WiFi without having to restart the Pi?

Comment: If no `id_str` given, the value will be `default`.

Comment: where can I read about `wpa-roam` and `wpa-config` and other wpa_supplicant statements in `/etc/network/interfaces`? Neither `man interfaces` nor `man wpa_supplicant.conf` have anything about those statements

Comment: @MetalGodwin You can use `wpa_cli` as suggested here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=179387

Comment: After I fixed my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, I also restart services of wpa_supplicant and networking via `systemctl`. It's working now.

Answer (score 51):

With Raspbian `Jessie` release, you don't have to edit the `interface` file. Just updating the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file with multiple networks would suffice. Here's how it looks -

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="SCHOOLS NETWORK NAME"
    psk="SCHOOLS PASSWORD"
    id_str="school"
}

network={
    ssid="HOME NETWORK NAME"
    psk="HOME PASSWORD"
    id_str="home"
}
```

This worked for me and my wifi is always connected to the list of available networks mentioned in the above file. Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not appear to work if you specify `id=` but if you instead specify a `priority=` for each then it does work.

Comment: If you edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file, you need to restart the demon to get it to read the new .conf: 
sudo killall -HUP wpa_supplicant

Comment: You can also run `wpa_passphrase my_SSID my_password` and it will return the config needed to put into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: One-liner: `sudo sh -c 'wpa_passphrase my_SSID my_password >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'`

Answer (score 43):

I recently stumbled across a console application that sorts all the wireless configuration hell out. *You can also use this tool to configure the LAN interface.*

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
```

It will install quite a few other packages but it runs its own daemon in the background. This manages the networks and makes sure you connect to the ones you want. Run it with:

```
sudo wicd-curses
```

[image: Screenshot of wicd-curses]

If you get a message saying no networks detected press `P` (must be capital so use [SHIFT]p) and type in wlan0 in the wireless interface field and press F10 to save.

1. `R` to refresh the list.
2. Use the cursors on the keyboard to navigate up and down the list
3. Press right to configure the wireless connection
4. Press down a few times and check "Automatically connect to this network"
5. Press down a  few times again and type in your password in the key field
6. Press F10 to save
7. Start from 1 to do this again for any other networks

[image]

You might have to press `C` to connect to the access point. If you were connected via cable, that will most likely kill the LAN interface and bring up wireless.

It is also manages the connection so it will reconnect to any configured wireless access points if it drops out for whatever reason but it will also try to connect to any available networks, just like in Windows, Macintosh or Linux Desktops.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this type of tool is exactly what I was looking for. all of the flexibility offered by the GUI, but terminal instead. Thank you!

Comment: Upvote:  After running this I did an Advanced IP Scan of the two subnets and my Rpi3 shows up on both of them.  Interestingly, when I went to install this initially, it told me I already had the latest version.

Comment: One minor detail:  To get extra range I am using wlan1 with an external antenna, so in curses I had to go into prefs to specify that adapter.  There was no need to shut off wlan0 but I did it anyway with sudo ifcongig wlan0 down.

Comment: Unfortunately `wicd-curses` is not included in the repositories anymore. It also depends on python2

Comment: Use `sudo nmtui` instead (from the `network-manager` package, which I believe comes preinstalled).

Answer (score 24):

Actually you can add the priority option. Like so:

```
network={
      ssid="open"
      key_mgmt=NONE
      id_str="open"
      priority=3
}

network={
        ssid="secure"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        proto=WPA2
        group=CCMP
        pairwise=CCMP
        eap=TLS
        ca_cert="/etc/certs/cacert.pem"
        client_cert="/etc/certs/client.pem"
        private_key="/etc/certs/client.key"
        private_key_passwd="somepwd"
        identity="me"
        priority=5
}

network={
        ssid="AndroidAP"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=WPA2
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
        psk="SomeP4ssw0rd"
        priority=4
}


network={
        ssid="Spooky"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        group=WEP104
        psk="A4ABC2FC27412D4D23CAEBCA23"
        priority=2
}

network={
        ssid="another"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=WPA2
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
        psk="A very long and secret passphrase here"
        priority=1
}
```

priority: when multiple networks are available simultaneously, the one with the highest priority value is selected.

id_str: for each network, you can give this parameter a specific value (a string). If none is provided, "default" is used as text string. This string is used in /etc/network/interfaces as a virtual interface identifier. This allow creating specific configuration blocks for each network. The only requirement is to have the physical interface using the "inet manual" method (this is a MUST).

Comment: Just double-checking here, priority is enclosed in asterisks? From what I read, they're not supposed to be enclosed in double-asterisks, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: @ericmjl He tried to bold the code, I'll edit it.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically rescan and see if a higher priority network is available and switch?

Comment: @Michal Yes, have a background process running that does just that.

Comment: @les How would that work, which command?

Comment: @Michal just set up a script that checks the strength every desired length of time

Comment: Combine this with WPA supplicant on startup, ssh, and the ".local" addresses and you have a nice recipe for connecting the pi.

Comment: Does "higher priority" mean a larger or a smaller integer?

Comment: What is the purpose of `priority` in the context of the question?  The OP was clear that the networks won't be available simultaneously.

Comment: @deanresin: Good pont  :) No one seems to be aware of the fact that when `priority` is equal for all networks configured in `wpa_supplicant.conf` (which is the *default*, the one with the strongest signal will be selected.

Answer (score 10):

It's April, 2022, and this question of ***"How to setup multiple WiFi networks?"*** now has a straightforward answer:

If you use multiple WiFi networks in different locations, all that is needed is to configure each of these networks in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` - configure as many as you need!

The `wpa_supplicant.conf` file proposed in the currently selected answer is still correct, though **the `id_str` is optional**:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1 

network={
    ssid="SCHOOLS NETWORK NAME"
    psk="SCHOOLS PASSWORD"
}
    
network={
    ssid="HOME NETWORK NAME"
    psk="HOME PASSWORD"
}
```

Unless you are "Home Schooled", *which is to say that two or more networks are available in a given location*, it's not necessary to create a `priority` for the networks :)  By default, all networks listed in `wpa_supplicant.conf` have equal priority, and when priority is equal
`wpa_supplicant` will choose the network with the greatest signal strength (all other things being equal). This will come as a disappointment to the *knob turners*, but beyond properly defining the networks in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, there is really nothing else to be done in the situation defined by the OP.

If you do have two or more networks in a given location, then a `priority` assignment to your "favored" network may be appropriate. Another exception may be that you have a need to switch between networks. If you need to dynamically switch between networks, - [there's another answer for that](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136933/83790). Otherwise, leave it alone.

Readers should carefully consider adopting networking advice in a *piecemeal* fashion; there are numerous fallacies and foolishness embedded in some of the answers and comments here. Some that I noticed:

- > Then set up /etc/network/interfaces with iface school inet static and iface home inet static

  Two major ***no-nos*** here:

  1. `dhcpcd` now handles network management for RPi - this file should not be edited unless you know what you're doing
  2. static ip assignment is almost **never** a good idea - esp. when you're using a network you don't manage.
- > If you edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file, you need to restart the demon to get it to read the new .conf ...

  No - not true; that *may* work, but a less disruptive method is to use the `wpa_cli` app to handle this; [see the ArchWiki for details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant)

And there are others, but impossible to list them all here. Be diligent - and that goes for this answer also!

Comment: A small note: If you make wifi-related changes in raspi-config *after* making the change to the conf, it runs `wpa_cli save_config` which "updates" the config, wiping the changes you made. You can instead use wpa_cli directly to add the networks. I don't have the rep for this exchange to add an answer directly on this "Highly active question", so a comment will have to do. Run `wpa_cli`, the way to add the first network is: `add_network`, `set_network 0 ssid MySSID`, `set_network 0 psk MyPassword`, `set_network 0 disabled 0`, `quit`, then run `wpa_cli save_config` to finish.