# How to get Wi-Fi to connect on boot?

Tags: raspbian, wireless, wifi, headless

Raspberry Pi Model B
OS: Raspbian

I am running my Pi headless (currently through a direct Ethernet connection). I have a USB WiFi dongle. I would like to have the WiFi start up at boot and connect by DHCP.

http://rpi.tnet.com/project/faqs/headlessportablewifi suggests that I don't need to actually change **/etc/network/interfaces** from the default:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

I have configured **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** for my network.

When I boot the Pi, WiFi does not immediately connect. But if I SSH in and run `sudo ifup wlan0`, the Pi connects fine.

Isn't this something the Pi should do in its own boot process? I could presumably write tell some dotfile to run this command, but I would like to do it the proper way (and learn how my system works).

I know I can also set a static IP address for each WiFi network I want to use: [How to setup multiple WiFi networks?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/wifi-setup-for-multiple-networks/11738). But I would prefer to have a simple solution where I only have to enter a couple lines on **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** to add a new WiFi network.

What is the piece I am missing here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default Raspbian **/etc/network/interfaces** configuration does not connect to WiFi on boot. The key lines of the interfaces man-page are:

> Lines  beginning with the word "auto" are used to identify the
>   physical interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the
>   -a  option.  (This option is used by the system boot scripts.)
>
> ...
>
> Lines  beginning with the word "auto" are used to identify the
>    physical interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the
>    -a  option.  (This option is used by the system boot scripts.)

The first missing piece was the line `auto wlan0`. As far as I know, it can go anywhere in the file.

That works until you try booting without the ethernet cable plugged in. Then, WiFi doesn't connect on boot and has to be manually triggered by running `sudo ifup wlan0` or unplugging and reinserting the Wi-Fi dongle.

The problem is caused by the **ifplugd** daemon, which turns network devices on and off when you plug them in or remove them. You can reconfigure it, or you can simply remove it with `sudo apt-get purge ifplugd`.

If you have removed **ifplugd**, you should add the following lines to **/etc/network/interfaces** so that the ethernet connection will also connect when plugged in:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
```

I'm not sure if the  `auto` lines are strictly necessary or if hotplug handles booting correctly in the absence of **ifplugd**, but this worked for me.

My working file reads:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: do you have a typo at "auth eth0"? should it be "auto eth0"?

Comment: a small correction of @katriel s post: The service which needs to be removed is called **ifplugd** and not **ifupd**

Comment: @DH1TW and six months later... I will never write one of these things from memory again

Comment: For the record, I'm using wpa_supplicant so I just enabled the service ``sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service``

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Check the r/w settings of your `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I did `chmod 600 /etc/network/interfaces` and my problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can enable WiFi on boot by just creating a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the `boot` partition, which will be copied into the `/etc/wpa_supplicant` directory and used by the wpa_supplicant daemon so that it connects to the specified network(s) . This can be done when preparing the SDcard on another machine before insertion into the Pi. The `wpa_supplicant.conf` should contain something like this (for more details see  the [Raspberry Pi site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid="YourWiFi"
    psk="YourPassword"
}
```