# How to connect Raspberry pi to wi-fi network?

Tags: wifi, ssh

I want to connect my raspberry pi to wi-fi and this wi-fi uses ip address.
I use raspberry pi model 2 (B+), I have wi-fi dongle. How do I connect?
I have connected to pi using ssh, and I'm only able to access the command line of pi and don't have access to it's GUI.

EDIT::

```
>> cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: What distro do you use? There are quite a lot of guides out there about configuring wireless from cli on various distros. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Can you check the below answer and confirm if it works for you. Post if you are having any errors.

Comment: @VaradAG where do I specify the ip address of the wi-fi which I'm supposed to connect to? Moreover there is no password for the wi-fi acess,

Comment: no, not a static one, I have to change the proxy settings manually specifying the proxy hostname and proxy port

Comment: @kvmanohar looks like the one I posted would not help you to get the issue resolved. There is a example here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921. This should help

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi Foundation has [a guide on setting up WiFi without a GUI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

To summarize:

Use the following to scan for available WiFi networks:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

This will bring up a list of available networks, make a note of the ssid of your network.  Then open and edit the wpa-supplicant configuration file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Once open, add the following to the end of the file:

```
network={
ssid="The ssid"
psk="The router password"
}
```

The ssid is the network name you found earlier, the password is the normal WiFi password.  You may need to reboot.

You can check that this is running:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

There should be an IP address under inet addr.

Comment: This would automatically reconnect every time rpi is restarted or wifi connection is restarted from host?

Comment: For automatic connection, you will need to add 'auto wlan0' followed by 'allow-hotplug wlan0' to the /etc/network/interfaces file.  See this [Stackexchange question for a full answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13558/how-to-get-wi-fi-to-connect-on-boot).

Comment: `auto wlan0` is no longer necessary. The default `/etc/network/interfaces` should NOT need to be modified. NOTE the linked answer is OBSOLETE.