# Pi not Connecting to Wi-Fi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I followed the same steps in this [Adafruit Wi-Fi Setup](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis) but I am not Getting Connection in Pi

This is output during lsusb  and  iwlist scan

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9041 NetGear, Inc. WNA1000M 802.11bgn [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ iwlist scan
    wlan0     Scan completed :
              Cell 01 - Address: 70:62:B8:BB:FE:8D
                        ESSID:"NANDI"
                        Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                        Mode:Master
                        Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                        Encryption key:on
                        Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                        Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
                        IE: WPA Version 1
                            Group Cipher : TKIP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                        IE: Unknown: DD7C0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010630412531019200612287062B8BBFE8D10210006442D4C696E6B1023000752544C383637311024000D45562D323030362D30372D32371042000C3730363262386262666538341054000800060050F20400011011000944534C2D3237353055100800020086
                        Quality=0/100  Signal level=100/100  

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

[image]

This is /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 iface eth0 inet dhcp

 allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

 iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "SSID"
        wpa-psk "PASSWORD"
```

And Also I tried Like this Post [wifi setup for multiple networks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/wifi-setup-for-multiple-networks) 2nd answer i.e USER ppumkin's answer

It is showing the Wi-fi Connection when I

```
sudo wicd-curses
```

Even I Configured the Same Way, but When I click "C" it is disconnecting From LAN As Specified By [USER]ppumkin, but It is not Connecting to Wi-Fi.
[image]

I am Checking it with a webserver.. I've Installed Apache In Pi. Using Wired Network I will Get Index.Html but with Wi-Fi I am Not Getting the Index Page

Comment: What does dmesg report for the wifi dongle?  The contents of /etc/network/interfaces would probably be useful.

Comment: @joan I have added the /etc/network/interface... I've Removed My SSID and Password

Comment: See what dmesg says when the dongle is plugged in.  So remove the dongle, wait a couple of seconds, reinsert the dongle.  Have a look at the last few lines of the dmesg command output.  What does it have to say about the dongle?

Answer (score 1):

I think that, like most of us, you have ended up with a confused set of configuration statements. I expect you've fixed it by now, but others may find this useful. This assumes a modern WPA2 setup.

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` should be:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="myWifiNetworkName"
    psk="myWifiPassword"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

For an older system proto could be WPA and pairwise could be TKIP. Then in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```