# Multiple Wifi Networks: Connect to Strongest Signal

Tags: networking, wifi

Following the instructions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/wifi-setup-for-multiple-networks), I was able to setup my *pi* to connect to two different wifis.

The two wifis are in the same place and I would like the *pi* to connect to the one with the strongest signal. Right now if both APs are on, my *pi* keeps connecting to a specific AP ignoring the AP with the stronger signal.

How can I accomplish that the *pi* connects to the AP with the strongest signal?

Answer (score 2):

It would helpful if you could post the config file you have, i believe it may be connecting to the first AP in the list , as this will obviously be the first one to try.

It will connect to the strongest available network when first connecting, but, by default, once connected it will not change networks unless it loses its connection first. This is presumably because switching would involve disconnecting existing connections, and a second or three of no network.

One solution might be to set up a single SSID with two access points that support hand-off, rather than two entirely seperate wifi networks - which is the way that this sort of scenario is handled in large commercial settings - but I do not know whether that is feasible with the hardware that you have.

Comment: Yes, you're right! The one with the weaker signal is the first in the list but both wifis are on and the Pi still keeps connecting to the weaker one. Unfortunately, changing the wifi structure is not an option.

Comment: What distro are you running on the PI?
It may be that there is a service you could start on boot that would accuratly measure the wifi strength and switch accordingly. ive done this on android and it worked well. Havent needed to do something like this on my RPi though