# Multiple wlan DHCP

Tags: wifi

I tried using `wpa-supplicants` to be able to connect to multiple WiFi's (not simultaneously).

This only works with `manual` it seems and not with DHCP. Writing the SSID and the password directly in `/etc/network/interfaces` works for one network.

From the interfaces file it seems only one network can be specified. Any ideas?

EDIT: By 2 networks I mean my wireless home network and e.g. the network at university. I want my pi to have a (un)ordered list of networks and I want to connect to one available. It is enough, when this happens on startup, but it would be nice if it tries to reconnect, when the connection is lost..

Comment: If you are referring to moving between wireless networks and connecting to whichever is active at the time, take a look at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/wifi-setup-for-multiple-networks).

Comment: I use `wicd-curses` - It saved allot of time messing around with that supplicant file. The answer here shows you how to use if for reconnecting, but you can use it to "remember" many hot spots, and it will autoconnect to the strongest one. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9750/894

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically reconnect WiFi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi)

Comment: @bobstro : This is what I need with one important change: This method only works with an static IP. I need it to work with dhcp

Comment: @ppumkin : I do not have a screen or any other access to the pi of it ideas not connected to a WiFi. As far as I got it it is impossible to use the tool via ssh and the same WiFi (tried) or to connect to an network not in reach... Thanks for all your answers :)

Comment: Have you tried simply using something like `iface home inet dhcp`?

Comment: @ppumkin one problem with these answers is that THEY ARE NOT APPLICABLE to anyone using the new distributions using `dhcpcd`. The only methods which work reliably are https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md If you know what you are doing you can restore old behaviour, but this requires detailed knowledge and is not suitable for new users. Sadly the Foundation is going the same was as Microsoft & Apple and making things "simpler".

Comment: As far as I understood the syntax the element right after "iface" had to be the hardware path (wlan0 in my case)

Comment: @bobstro : Notifying you as I forgot in yesterday's comment of mine...

Comment: pay attention to `id_str` in the 1st answer to the question I linked to. That's the key to what you need to enter in your `/etc/network/interfaces`.