# How to set up multiple wifi networks?

Tags: wifi, watchdog

I know how to set up multiple wifi networks, as in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/11631/17729). However, I have additional needs not addressed there:

First: How do I know which network made the connection (for instance, in the example, I would like to know if the network is school or work)?

Second: How can I set up the Raspberry Pi as an access point if no network connection is made (I assume this will need some kind of script, but I don't know how to write it)?

Third: How can I check every few minutes if the connection is still active, and automatically reset the connection if it is not (perhaps this is a use case for watchdog, but I've never used that)?

Comment: You linked to a very old post. Are we supposed to guess which parts of it you followed. If you want help post YOUR OWN configuration. You have asked 3 separate questions, which would attract quite different answers.

Comment: I used [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11738/17729). My configuration has 5 different networks, each with appropriate entries in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. I have successfully connected to two of those networks, but haven't yet been able to try connecting to the other three. Yes, I asked three different questions, but they are all related, and someone interested in one of them might very likely be interested in the others, so I asked them all here in one place.

Comment: You should ask three single questions.