# Set up multiple WiFi Networks (Phone hotspots)

Tags: pi-4, hotspot

I want to be able to connect through different phones' hotspots (Pi4 - operating system of last June - the Pi has a static IP).

I am only able to connect to the latest phone that was connected and wpa_supplicant shows the others as disabled=1

I followed this post:
[How to setup multiple WiFi networks?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/how-to-setup-multiple-wifi-networks)

But every time I modify wpa_supplicant the file goes back to its original script.
Basically:

1. I delete `disabled=1`,
2. I add the `priority`
3. and I add names for the `id_str`
4. then I press CTRL+X and Y

However nothing changes and I am only able to connect to the latest phone's hotspot the pi was connected.

If I re-open `wpa_supplicant.conf` just after I supposedly change it the file it is in its original format including the disabled=1, no priorities and id_str.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tested whether your SDCard has failed info "read only" mode.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The SD card was ok. I solved the issue following the PI official documentation linked bellow. I do not know why the networks not used last were disabled but I had the same issue with several PIs and I had to manually reconfigure them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?"

Using the Network icon on the Desktop to change WiFi networks.

This is how it is DESIGNED to work, and is the only (reliable) way of MANUALLY switching networks.

You could set `update_config=0` - but then you can't use the Network icon to change WiFi networks.

There should be no need to MANUALLY switch networks on a correctly configured  `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

PS setting static IP is a recipe for disaster with different hotspots. It **MAY** work if they ALL use the most common setting.

Incidentally that post is hopelessly out of date. Following any 8 year old tutorial is dangerous.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the PI documentation linked in your post and managed to delete the "disable=1" I do not know why it was there in first place. I think that the old post should be perhaps closed? Or at least a link on your tutorial provided?