# Why does adding a 2nd network in wpa_supplicant.conf break my wifi connection to Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

Following [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40144/149966) I added a 2nd WiFi network to `wpa_supplicant` on my bullseye installation.

There must be something wrong with the configuration as when I reboot the router I am unable to connect to the Raspberry Pi on either network, effectively leaving me no way to connect to the device via SSH.

The configuration I used is:

```bash
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETWORK1 NAME"
    psk=<secure version of psk added when configuring pi with imager software>
    id_str=""network_1
}

network={
    ssid="NETWORK2 NAME"
    psk=PASSWORD2
    id_str=""network_2
}
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

Comment: You've missed adding the country code with `country=xx` after `update_config=1` where xx is your ISO country code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: `Following this answer I added a 2nd WiFi network` ... no, you did not follow the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

First error:

```
id_str=""network_1
```

should look like this

```
id_str="network_1"
```

And the same for `network_2`

And the second error:

If you read the first comment on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40144/149966

> This does not appear to work if you specify id= but if you instead
> specify a priority= for each then it does work. –  Ian Mercer Oct 21,
> 2020 at 3:37

So add a `priority=1` and `priority=2` to `network_1` and `netwwork_2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no point in attempting to use a 7 year old post for an obsolete OS!

There are OBVIOUS formatting errors in the strings you entered. Even if you corrected the `id_str` entry it is doubtful that these serve any useful purpose in modern networking.

You have NOT set a country=

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)