# wpa-roam can only be used with the manual inet method

Tags: raspbian, wifi, static-ip

I'm trying to setup my new Wifi dongle I've bought from ModMyPi.

Its working for DHCP but when I try to make it a static IP, I get this error when restarting it:

`wpa-roam can only be used with the manual inet METHOD`

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here is my `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="My-Wifi"
    psk="my_password"
}
```

I don't know what else to do to get it to use `192.168.1.2` as its static IP wirelessly. Help?

---

If it helps, I have a BTHomeHub3 with a WPA & WPA2 compatible key and my SSID is visible.

---

**UPDATE** I would like my configuration to support multiple wifi networks setup so that when I move to and from University and Home, My Raspberry Pi can just work wirelessly.

My files are currently like so:

`/etc/network/interfaces`: http://pastebin.com/HeP8kgBR
`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`: http://pastebin.com/RaFkEAx6

---

**UPDATE** When I run `sudo ifup wlan0` now I am getting this error:

```
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure the ssid is correct?  Did you set up the wifi with the wpa_gui on the desktop environment or from the command line? Are you using "madwifi"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I got it working as I wanted, here is what I did.

I restored the original `/etc/network/interfaces` file and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to make sure those aren't an issue.

I then ran `startx` to launch into the GUI and used WiFi Config to scan for my network and set it up. When setting it up, I specified the ID at the bottom of the setup window and called it `home`.

I then edited `/etc/network/interfaces` to add `iface home inet static` and defined my static IP information.

After a reboot, it worked perfectly!

Thanks everybody for your help, the GUI was the best way in the end.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working! If you could mark your self-answer (this one) as answer, that would be great! We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and that would help us a lot!

Comment: No problem! Again, glad to here you got the issue resolved! Also, if you plan on being active around here, pop into the chat from time to time! We always love company and it shows that this site is active and has an involved user base.

Answer (score 3):

In `/etc/network/interfaces` Change **iface wlan0 inet static** to **iface wlan0 inet manual**

Now put in a new line:

> iface somenamehere inet static

Then cut the wlan0 static IP info(not the wpa-roam part) and paste it underneath. Your *interfaces* file should now look like:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface somenamehere inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Note: I leave out *network* and *broadcast* from my static IP configuration and it always works fine.

Now in `wpa_supplicant.conf` add the line

> id_str="somenamehere"

In the network setting part. It should now look like:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="My-Wifi"
    psk="my_password"
    id_str="somenamehere"
}
```

Change *somenamehere* to anything you like.

Look at my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11738/966) for more info on setting up wpa_supplicant.conf with multiple networks

Comment: Nope still not working. Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`: http://pastebin.com/HeP8kgBR and here is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`: http://pastebin.com/RaFkEAx6

Comment: I added `allow-hotplug wlan0` to the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one network in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, rather than using `wpa-roam`, use `wpa-conf` as this will allow you to use static IP addresses.

Comment: Nope still not working

Comment: Still not working as in you get the same error message ? Also, the network and broadcast lines in the config aren't needed.

Comment: See other answer, I would like a multiple network setup so I can move to and from Home / University with ease.

Comment: this solved the error quoted in the question title for me, and it does in fact work if you have multiple networks defined in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, as each network defined in that file has a `priority` metric defined. good answer, apart from the incorrect assumption "If you only have on network in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.