# Pi with raspBMC as WiFi access point

Tags: networking, raspbmc

I want to setup my Pi running raspBMC to provide a WiFi access point.
There are many tutorials that work for raspbian e.g. https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview.

But these turorials do not work for raspBMC since raspBMC seams to use different network configuration mechanisms (e.g. as described in [Raspbmc network configuration file troubles](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/raspbmc-network-configuration-file-troubles)). It seems that raspBMC  does not read or gets confused by reading /etc/network/interfaces.

Did anybody get a WiFI access point running under raspBMC? Any hints on the specifics compared to e.g. raspbian would be very welcome.

Update 05.05.2014: 
I am using TP-Link TL-WN823N as wifi dongle. It is based on Realtek chipset.
Got the dongle working as access point under raspbian.
Did not get it working under raspBMC.
 
Did not get it working under openELEC (using the xbmc configuration menu item "enable tethering").

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't believe it would be a good idea to try and do this for two reasons:

A) Because if it isn't as straightforward as it is in Rasbian, then it will be a pain anyway.

B) Because the USB ports use the bandwidth from the Ethernet port (I know, strange). This is to save power, as the RPi is meant to have a low TCO (Total Cost of Ownership), so even if you DID get it working, and were, say, watching a movie on your Pi while having other devices connected to it doing other things, the bandwidth is shared, therefore making your connection slower for everybody on the network.